# Null Check on date

Tags: apex

I have put a null check on date

```
if(oli.opportunity.work_start_date__c != null)
            {
                olis.ScheduleDate = (oli.opportunity.work_start_date__c.addMonths(i-1));
                system.debug('schedate '+olis.ScheduleDate);
            }    
            olis.type = 'revenue';

            if(oli.opportunity.work_start_date__c != null)
            {
               if(i==1)
               {
                   olis.revenue = (30 - oli.opportunity.work_start_date__c.Day())/30 * oli.unitPrice;
                   system.debug('i=1 ='+olis.revenue);
               }

               else if(i>1 && i<n)
               {
                       olis.revenue = (30/30) * oli.unitPrice;
                       system.debug('i=more ='+olis.revenue);
               }

               else
               {
                   olis.revenue = (oli.opportunity.work_start_date__c.Day()/30) * oli.unitPrice;
                   system.debug('i=n ='+olis.revenue);
               }
```

and the control is not going inside the if condition though the work_start_date__c(field) on opportunity is not null.
Do we have any other null check for  DATE.

Comment: Use isEmpty() instead

Comment: @crmprogdev Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Date].isEmpty()

Comment: I suggest using !ISBLANK(your_date__c)@Anzar

Comment: Put the variable inside the parens

Comment: Do you perhaps have two fields with the same label? So you think one is non-null but really in the code you are using a different field?

Comment: @AdrianLarson no its the same field Adrian...

Comment: @crmprogdev Put the variable inside the parens.. I didn't get you

Comment: Use `!isEmpty(oli.opportunity.work_start_date__c)`. isEmpty() covers `isBlank()` and `isNull()`. It's also what Salesforce will tell you is the preferred method.

Comment: @crmprogdev For a formula, you'd be correct. In Apex Code, a date field is either null or a Date value.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'd have to go back and look at archived code. I seem to recall that once a date field has been manipulated via Apex, unless explicitly set to null, when it's set to a blank value or a value that's not valid (it can happen), it will not return as null.

Comment: @crmprogdev If it could happen, it'd be a bug. I don't think I've ever seen it work that way before.

Answer (score 1):

SOQL has support for NULL values. For example:

SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE date_field != NULL

Comment: A date field can contain blank spaces. Null will not catch those situations.

Comment: @crmprogdev No, a date field cannot contain spaces.